# Enable terminal emulation in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ansi-escape

Many people have told me and the [PyCharm Release Notes for PyCharm 2.7](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/whatsnew_27.html) touts that *PyCharm* includes full terminal emulation (I assume this is talking about handling of *ANSI escape codes* for styling and cursor movement) but I can't seem to find out how to enable this.

I've enabled the *Terminal* plugin but when I try to *run* or *debug* a python application which makes use of these escape codes, they are just displayed raw in the console:

[image]

How can I enable the terminal emulation in PyCharm's debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Console and Terminal are two different things in PyCharm. Console is part of Run and Debug tool windows and is used only to show output from stdout and stderr whereas Terminal is separate tool window and makes it possible to interact with system shell. Support for ANSI escape codes in Console was added in version 14 of InteliJ (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69880) on 23 Jul 2014 and PyCharm 2.7.3 was released on 18 June 2013 so this feature is not present in PyCharm 2.7.