# Python wget module doesn't show progress bar

Tags: python

I am trying to download files in python using the wget module. I understand that it's supposed to have several progress bar modes but non actually show in the console.

I could not find any documentation for this module.

```py
import wget
from pathlib import Path

print('Beginning download...')

url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/meirtvmp3/archive/hebrew/mp3/sherki/daattvunot/idx_69115.mp3'
wget.download(url)
```

The file downloads but no progress bar shows.

The source code for the module does have a reference to it. But when I try it in my code python cant find a reference to it.

**EDIT**

I tested the script from the terminal and it worked as expected. I guess it's a pycharm/venv bug.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Are you running the code from a terminal? Do you redirect stdin and / or error?

Comment: funny I am able to run it from the terminal with `python - m wget url` I don't understand whats happening.

Comment: It probably just doesn't show progress bar by default when used from the Python api.

Comment: so how do I override that?

Comment: just `python foo.py` works as well. Since printing such a progress bar requires ANSI terminal sequences to be interpreted by the device where stdout points to, normally programs which render such bars are calling `isatty()` before enabling the feature. Otherwise it would screw up the output.

Comment: I can't reproduce. `python3 -c 'import wget; wget.download("http://httpbin.org")'` shows a bar for me.

Comment: right ^^^......

Comment: What platform and terminal are you on?

Comment: running windows 10 and pycharm

Comment: Try it in some other terminal like powershell or cygwin or git bash?

Comment: tried it in cmd and it worked as expected. it seems to have to do with pycharm

Comment: The terminal must support windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(). This is the function `wget.py` is using to probe on Windows

Comment: @hek2mgl if you could add some detail in a separate answer that I could except that would be good and we could close the question.

Comment: I think the behaviour is just intentional. Being able to display progress bars (==special control chars) is something which most _terminal emulators_ support, but it's a non standardized feature. The _console_ in pycharm just supports those minimal standardized featureset, but there is (I can't test this) also a _terminal_ in pycharm which support ANSI control chars. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985905/enable-terminal-emulation-in-pycharm

Comment: PS: I'm not answering because I don't have a Windows or Pycharm for testing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me,

```
#create this bar_progress method which is invoked automatically from wget
def bar_progress(current, total, width=80):
  progress_message = "Downloading: %d%% [%d / %d] bytes" % (current / total * 100, current, total)
  # Don't use print() as it will print in new line every time.
  sys.stdout.write("\r" + progress_message)
  sys.stdout.flush()

#Now use this like below,
url = 'http://url_to_download'
save_path = "/home/save.file"
wget.download(url, save_path, bar=bar_progress)
```

Comment: that's a good workaround for the bug/intended behavior in PyCharm. Can you expalin why the standered progress bars from `wget` don't work?

Comment: Trying this but getting a "403 Forbidden",  even though same url works with `wget` from the command line.