# What is wrong with PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I have no idea why PyCharm is doing this:

So, I have a .py file, and I have enabled "Emulate terminal in output console" for it.
Let's say I have this code:

```
print("Hello, World!")
print("Hello again!")
```

If I run it, I get this output:

```
Hello, World!
             Hello again!
```

What is going on?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV5TT.png)

EDIT 1: I reinstalled both Python and PyCharm, still the same issue!
However when I run it through the built-in Terminal menu the issue is gone?

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFYFd.png)

Comment: Weird. I wonder what happens if you put \n either at the end of the first quote or the start of the second one.

Comment: @Ben It's the same as before but there's an empty line in between them

Comment: Probably https://www.programmersought.com/article/29724237816/, disable it

Comment: would you like to add pycharm version, edition and OS details?

Comment: @ashfaq92 I use PyCharm 2022.2 Community edition. My OS is windows 10

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with pycharm. According to the [PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html):

> PyCharm includes an embedded terminal emulator for working with your command-line shell from inside the IDE. **Use it to run Git commands, set file permissions, and perform other command-line tasks without switching to a dedicated terminal application.**

A [stackoverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985905/enable-terminal-emulation-in-pycharm) notices:

> I've enabled the Terminal plugin but when I try to run or debug a python application which makes use of **these escape codes, they are just displayed raw in the console**

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985905/enable-terminal-emulation-in-pycharm):

> Console and Terminal are two different things in PyCharm. Console is part of Run and Debug tool windows and is used only to show output from stdout and stderr whereas Terminal is separate tool window and makes it possible to interact with system shell. Support for ANSI escape codes in Console was added in version 14 of InteliJ (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69880) on 23 Jul 2014 and PyCharm 2.7.3 was released on 18 June 2013 so this feature is not present in PyCharm 2.7.

**Conclusion**

When you try to see the output in the emulated terminal, it does not properly render the [escape sequences used in python print function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1580) that is why you see extra whitespace as the output and don't see such behavior when you see the output in a standard console.

Comment: I have been using the "Emulate terminal is output console" for some time now and never had this issue, but thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

They fixed this issue in the 2022.2.1 update LET'S GO!

edit: Pycharm 2022.2.1 update

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).